# With suitelet's external url unable to send mail

Tags: netsuite

We have an issue here. I don't know its by design or an issue that I'm only facing here. Its pretty strange that the same User Event is executing fine while I'm modifying a record through Suitelet's internal url but if I switched to external url its not working. Any guess why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Permission maybe? Under what role are you running the suitelet?

Comment: I checked with all roles even with Administrator but its strange. Its not working. @pipechang

Comment: Check on roles, must me all roles only. Also it may sometimes need some time to update... weirdly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution for that i am calling restlet with suitelet to invoke user event. wrote some code in restlet like update fields on record type. and user event will trigger. and write mail logic in user event so mail will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Security Reasons, if your Suitelet is available without login or as you've mentioned accessible by "External URL" that means the it can be accessed by anyone that doesn't have an access to your NetSuite account. Having said that, do you want to send an email triggered by a user whom you don't know? I guess not.

Comment: May be that issue.. But with 2015.2 release I have tested its working fine now...